# Is there a way to receive UDP datagrams with a source IPv4 address of 0.0.0.0 on Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

I have a piece of equipment that sends a stream of unicast UDP packets to a network interface on my Linux machine. I'm receiving them in my application using a normal UDP socket bound to `INADDR_ANY` and the expected destination port. The destination port and IP address in the datagrams are correct, but the source IP address in the IPv4 header is populated as `0.0.0.0` by the device.

I've found that when the source address is `0.0.0.0`, my calls to `recv()` on my socket never return any packets; they appear to be getting filtered somewhere in the OS UDP processing. I confirmed via `tcpdump` that the packets are being received (and this is what told me the source address was all zeros):

```
11:32:41.239706 50:12:34:80:07:2d > 09:22:45:ab:e8:90, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 4194: 0.0.0.0.84 > 192.168.137.144.10000: UDP, length 4152
```

Is there a way for me to configure my UDP socket so that the datagrams with this source address are not discarded? I have `rp_filter` configured to disable reverse-path filtering on all of my network interfaces already.

Comment: Have you checked (via a `-j LOG` match) that these invalid packets are making it all the way through iptables INPUT chain?

Comment: Is the source MAC address set correctly in these packets and only the source IP is missing, or is all source information missing?

Comment: I'll have to look into `iptables`; I'm not that experienced using it, so I'll have to figure out how to set that up. The source MAC address is populated correctly.

Comment: Have a look at http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/PacketFlow.png   Your packet needs to follow the path leading to "Local Processes".  Any one of the blocks it passes through could contain a rule discarding packets with invalid source address.

Comment: After looking into it a bit with `dropwatch`, it looks like the packets are being dropped in the `ip_rcv_finish()` kernel function, and drililng down into the kernel source from there, it appears that all packets received from a source address that is in the `0.0.0.0/8` network are marked as martians and rejected. By enabling `log_martians`, I also see this noted in the kernel log. It doesn't appear from what I can see in the source that this behavior is overridable in any way.